# Java Random.nextGaussian between 0 and 1

Tags: java, random, gaussian

I'm working on an image editor and I'm about to implement filters. I decided to go with some kind of blur or noise.

Anyway, I decided I wanted a uniform filter so I read up on `Random.nextGaussian()`.

However, since I'm working with RGB values that range from 0 to 255. How can I scale this random double value to fit within 0 and 255?

The random value returned by the nextGaussian() can range from -1 to 1 I believe.

So, I want to preserve the relative difference between the random values. "Scale" or "move the number range" if that makes sense.

I know it's possible but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Essentially, I need it to be a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is the reason for asking this question related to mixing up a Gaussian Blur and a Gaussian Distribution? The whole point of a Gaussian Distribution *is* to contain "all values" (with a peak around 0, as already said in the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you should use `nextDouble()`.

The *Gaussian* distribution is a distribution that ranges over the **entire collection of double values** (mathematically speaking, from **minus infinity** to **positive infinity**) with a peak around zero. The *Gaussian* distribution is thus **not uniform**.

The `nextDouble()` method draws numbers **uniformly** between `0` and `1` (`0` included, `1` excluded).

You can thus draw a number randomly between `0` and `255` (both inclusive) using the following code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int value = (int) math.floor(256.0*rand.nextDouble());
```

A faster algorithm is however masking a random integer (`Random.nextInt`):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int value = rand.nextInt()&0xff;
```

This algorithm isn't faster in big-oh analysis, but it saves one the more expensive `nextDouble` method call as well as a floating point multiplication and a float-to-int conversion.

Comment: Casting to `int` already does the equivalent of `Math.floor()`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: True, but most compilers will optimize this anyway and the code is more semantically readable (since people that don't know how values are rounded, can still understand it).

Answer (score 1):

You can fit Normal (Gaussian) distribution between ~[0,1] with adjusting mean and std. For example, use mean = 0.5, std = 0.15, and you will get value between [0,1] with total probability of 99.91%. In the end, you can ensure that value is strictly between [0,1].

[image: N(0.5,1.15)]

```
Supplier<Double> alphaSupplier = new Supplier<Double>() {
        
        @Override
        public Double get() {
            double value = new Random().nextGaussian() * 0.15 + 0.5;
            return Math.max(0, Math.min(1, value));
        }
    };
    
double random value = alphaSupplier.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nextGaussian() with Math.abs() so that you can obtain positive values of Gaussian distribution.

```
Random random = new Random();
double positiveRandomValue = Math.abs(random.nextGaussian());
```

Comment: Hi @MerveKaymak, not sure if you saw the other "accepted" answer (from 6 years ago) that also points out something important about the distribution.